# Unnecessary Variable declaration in Java?

Tags: java

Basically my question is in, which cases are variable declarations redundant? 
As an example:

```
        int[] number = new int[100]
        for ( int i = 1; i < number.length; i++ ) {
             if ( number[i] > max )
                 max = number[i];
             if ( number[i] < min )
                 min = number[i];
        }//End of For
    int range = max - min;
    System.out.println("The range is " + range);
```

Is the range variable good code or is it not necessary? It can be replaced by min - max in the print statement.

Comment: `good code` is generally subjective.

Comment: Good code is the one that is easy to understand and maintain.  If you believe that adding a variable (and naming it according to its purpose) improves the readability, then do not hesitate to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It all boils down to readability and maintainability of your code. For this simple expression `range` can be substituted by `max - min` but you may need the `range` value further down in your computation and continuously substituting it by `max - min` could become cumbersome. Having a single variable `range` would be more handy if it was frequently re-used.

Comment: Okay so in this case since the code ends after range is used once it is not needed, but in a much larger program it would maintain the readability.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your assessment. If the code ends here then you don't need to have a new variable.

Comment: But there is no reason not to have a new variable. I don't think it hurts anything.

Comment: It is one extra integer allocation on the stack frame but the cost of that (4 bytes) is negligible on modern day hardware, so yes, It doesn't hurt to have a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would write `int range = max - min;` however give you have the line

```
System.out.println("The range is "
```

it would be fair to assume that what ever comes after it should be the range.

```
System.out.println("The range is " + (max - min));
```

Note: if you are being inclusive the range is actually `max - min + 1` e.g. if max and min are the same, there is one possible number.

In Java 8 you can write

```
IntSummaryStatistics iss = IntStream.of(numbers)
                                    .summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("The range is " + (iss.getMax() - iss.getMin()));
```

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thank you, I knew it had to be simpler but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if an extra variable declaration makes the code more readable, it is good.

Do not think about extra variable assignments making your code perform worse or anything of that sort, let the compiler handle it. Depending on the case, the variable will be inlined anyway but you get the benefit of having more readable code.

Your example of having the `range` instead of `max - min` is somewhat bordering it in my opinion, but if the expression would be more complicated then yes, break it down in smaller, easier to understand parts. As an extra benefit it would make your code easier to refactor later on.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at `0` (not `1`), and you should try not reinvent the wheel. [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) can simplify getting the `min` and `max`. But you need to declare and initialzie `max` and `min`. And I'd prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Next, I believe it's a good practicle to reduce the scope of variables when possible. Something like,

```
int[] number = new int[100];
// populate number array... then,
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int num : number) {
    max = Math.max(max, num);
    min = Math.min(min, num);
}
int diff = max - min; // <-- only if you need it later...
System.out.printf("The range is %d - %d (%d diff)%n", min, max, diff);
```

Comment: The textbook I'm using in my CS class used the for loop I posted as the way to fin max values. We haven't really touched on the Math library yet. I ran this program after assigning each number in the array and saw that it worked but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @MilesGaitan Which part(s) did you not understand?

Comment: The for loop. What is meant by (int num : number)? I'm also not sure what max = Math.max(max, num).

Comment: It's a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (Javadoc link in answer and here). It can be read as for each `int num` in the array (or `Collection`) `number`.

Comment: Okay I see what the for-each loop is now. So for each number in the array it will test if it is the maximum number or minimum number.